# How Dynamically Transfer data in All Google Sheets based on Filter Data automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I am using Google Sheet for recording my stock. I am trying to automate everything. There are multiple sheets with stock names. I have one sheet title "History1" where I input data manually and I build the following code to segregate all the data in the respective sheets. Here is the link of Sheet [Trade Binance Google  Sheet Tracker](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KD_qFT6J6ife72OhQRzr0pHSiyyRNA3X8KCDTc2A-iE/edit#gid=1709254924)

I have written the following script but it is giving me errors and does not work correctly.

```
function split_history(){
  
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var hissht=ss.getSheetByName("History1");
  var hisvals=hissht.getDataRange().getValues();
  var sheets=ss.getSheets();
  for (i=0;i<sheets.length;i++){
    if (sheets[i].getName()=="Summary" || sheets[i].getName()=="History1" || sheets[i].getName()=="Main Menu" ) {} else {
      var sn=sheets[i].getName();
      var vals=[];
      for (j=1;j<hisvals.length;j++){
        if (hisvals[j][8]==sn){
          vals.push([hisvals[j][0],hisvals[j][1],hisvals[j][2],hisvals[j][3],hisvals[j][4],hisvals[j][5],hisvals[j][6],hisvals[j][7]]) ; //modify it as per your need
        }
      }
      var dsht=ss.getSheetByName(sn);
      var dlr=dsht.getLastRow();
      dsht.getRange(dlr+1,1,vals.length,8).setValues(vals); //i have used only 4 columns A,B,C,D - you can modify it

    }
  }
}
//
```

It is giving me the [image]following error code.

Please check it and suggest to me where I am doing wrong. Thanks

[image: Cooper code Error Please review it. Thanks]

Comment: When you say `it does not work correctly` what exactly do you mean? Does it populate some sheets and then error, or does it not populate any at all? I'm thinking this might be coming from the case where there are no transactions to enter into a sheet, in which case an `if (vals.length === 0) continue` line before the `dsht.getRange(dlr+1,1,vals.length,8).setValues(vals)` might fix it.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Thanks, my code is already working and I fixed it but now I am facing issue that, the data is populated at the last blank row,  because, the column J:N containing formula and code consider the rows from A2:H as data rows. So, I want that, code should populate data on the next emply cell so that it get Column A2 cell and fill first value then B2:H2 and fill all columns. Now it should move to the next blank column instead of next blank row due to formula in cells from J:N. I hope you get my point.

Comment: I think it would be best posed as a new question to get more attention. Also, if you solved the issue, consider posting how you did it as an answer so that future users with a similar issue may be able to find the solution too :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function split_history() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const hsh = ss.getSheetByName("History1");
  const hvs = hsh.getRange(2,1,hsh.getLastRow() -1,9).getValues();
  const shts = ss.getSheets();
  const excl  = ["Summary","History1","Main Menu"];
  shts.forEach(s => {
    let oA = [];
    if(!~excl.indexOf(s.getName())) {
      hvs.forEach(r => {
        if(s.getName() == r[0]) {
          oA.push(r.slice(0,8));
        }
      });
      s.getRange(getColumnHeight(1,s,ss) + 1,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
    }
  });
}
```

If you'll put a header row in everyone of the sheets your writing too and lock it.  It will be helpful when viewing data and it will keep you from getting that error because there will always be at least one row in the sheet.

```
function getColumnHeight(col, sh, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rcA = [];
  if (sh.getLastRow()){ rcA = sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat().reverse(); }
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rcA.length; i++) {
    if (rcA[i].toString().length == 0) {
      s++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length - s;
}
```

Comment: 10:20:48 AM Notice Execution started
10:20:49 AM Error 
ReferenceError: sh is not defined
split_history1 @ Split_History_Final.gs:28

Comment: Try it again I get use to using the same variables all of the time and threw in my common term for sheet.

Comment: My code is working good, but it is not populating the result next empty cell from column A to H but it is populating results, where the row is totally blank. If you see the sheet there you will see that row 3 and from column J to R contain some formulas. So the code is populating results where, a row has no formula, at the beneath of the formula rows. can you fix that one?

Comment: Oh so you have other data on the page in the same row.  But you were using getLastRow() to get the location of the next line.  How was that working?

Comment: I think the `getColumnHeight()` function will solve that problem.

Comment: can you please modify code and sent me here to that I can test it. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.  In what way do you need it modified?

Comment: I mean can you update my code so that it can populate values from row 2 to onward?

Comment: If you be a bit more specific about your needs then yes I could do that.   Currently the code is reading data from line 2 of the History1 sheet down to the last row and populating the sheets listed in column one of `hsh` starting from line two if your willing to add a fixed and frozen header to each of the new sheets.  It will continue to do that as you added more sheets/tabs to the spreadsheet.

Comment: i have run the code but it is not working. It's giving an error.

Comment: Am I supposed to deduce the error or are you going to share it with us?

Comment: bro I have add screenshot in my post it says that,

Comment: 12:27:54 PM Notice Execution started
12:27:55 PM Error 
ReferenceError: vs is not defined
(anonymous) @ Split_History_Final.gs:34
split_history1 @ Split_History_Final.gs:31

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236130/discussion-between-ali-ahmer-rahil-and-cooper).